# Is there a difference between Coded UI and Unit Test projects?

Tags: win-universal-app, coded-ui-tests

I have a Windows 10 UWP that I want to do UI testing for. These two pages
https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver
https://medium.com/@yostane/automated-ui-testing-of-a-uwp-app-using-appium-dc10d8df6631#.kt3xoi3jb

use Unit Test Projects rather than Coded UI projects. The latter link even says there's no difference. Does it really matter? Are their any coded UI examples out there, or for Win 10 UWP apps, will the above two links suffice?

This does not seem like a duplicate of the asked question in the link that I got moderated for-I'm asking if there's a diff between Coded UI Test Projects or Unit Test Projects in VS. Since both of those links I mentioned use the latter, (including MSFT's official GitHub account) I'm a little confused. I'm doing UI testing, its not a matter of UI vs Unit Testing. Just what kind of VS solution is the preferred one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit tests with view models or coded ui test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631484/unit-tests-with-view-models-or-coded-ui-test)

Comment: Looks like this may be moot. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095583/error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-smallicon-while-creating-coded-ui my version of VS (pro) doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to know a method to run tests. I think both are excelent tools to run tests. I use CodedUI because

- I can do picture verifications
- I can drag and drop items
- I can connect it with TFS (shared tables)
- I can run the test in a build

Probably CodedUI is better in continues delivery.

Answer (score 0):

The question "Just what kind of VS solution is the preferred one." is a broad question with no single good answer.

I have use Appium and the WinApp Driver, as well as having Unit tests using  [Xunit](https://xunit.github.io/). The two, Appium and XUnit, address different problems. Appium for the UI side and Xunit for unit tests.

By that I mean, [Unit Tests Don’t Test The UI](http://blog.smartbear.com/testing/unit-testing-vs-ui-testing/), and I included a link to explain what I mean. 
But if you're asking just which testing platform to use for UI testing in VS, then Appium is, IMO, the future for Windows UI testing, so it makes sense to prefer it.